# Magify effect with fabric js

Tags: fabricjs, magnify

Is there is any way to magnify fabric js canvas objects magnify?

I have tried with help of so many examples but mostly magnify the image only, i need to magnify any objects present in canvas like rect, circle, text, image

Comment: also i have tried to modify this by passing canvas dataUrl image like the following URL https://jsfiddle.net/ankur02/kvht1637/

Comment: Use scaleX and scaleY properties

Comment: frabic comes with it's own zoom helper: `canvas.setZoom(val);`

Comment: any example for the same so i can get idea

Comment: @JonasGiuro we have already use canvas.setZoom for the zoom in and zoom out functionality, now i need to zoom perticular section with mouse hover like jsfiddle.net/ankur02/kvht1637

Comment: we can achieve the magnify by passing canvas data uri and canvas width and height